# Shared secret from mbedtls_ecdh_compute_shared() is all 0x00

Tags: cryptography, mbedtls, ecdh

I am working with mbedtls in a 32-bit microcontroller and have created a ECDH context. I put in the X and Y coordinates of the other party's public key, then attempt to create the shared secret.  The shared secret that I am getting is all 0x00.  The pertinent lines of code are shown below.  key_size = 32.  What am I missing/doing wrong?

```
  //Initialize the Static ECDH context and retrieve the static public key
  mbedtls_ecdh_init(&ECDH_Context_Static);
  mbedtls_ecp_group_load(&ECDH_Context_Static.grp, ElipticCurveID);
  mbedtls_ecdh_gen_public(&ECDH_Context_Static.grp, &ECDH_Context_Static.d, &ECDH_Context_Static.Q, mbedtls_ctr_drbg_random, &DRBG_Context);
  mbedtls_mpi_write_binary(&ECDH_Context_Static.Q.X, StaticPublicKey_X, key_size);  //Write to char array from ECDH context -> copy out static public key
  mbedtls_mpi_write_binary(&ECDH_Context_Static.Q.Y, StaticPublicKey_Y, key_size);

  //Generate a Static shared secret using local Static private key and Host's Static public key
  success = mbedtls_mpi_read_binary(&ECDH_Context_Static.Qp.X, HostStaticPublicKey_X, key_size); //Read to ECDH context from char array -> load in Host's public key
  success = mbedtls_mpi_read_binary(&ECDH_Context_Static.Qp.Y, HostStaticPublicKey_Y, key_size);
  success = mbedtls_ecdh_compute_shared(&ECDH_Context_Static.grp, &ECDH_Context_Static.z, &ECDH_Context_Static.Qp, &ECDH_Context_Static.d, NULL, NULL);
  success = mbedtls_mpi_write_binary(&ECDH_Context_Static.z, StaticSecret, key_size); //Write to char array from ECDH context -> copy out static shared secret
```

Comment: PS - Sorry about the code formatting, I just wasn't able to figure out how to insert the code with good formatting (and it looks even worse in the final version than in the review version).

Comment: I have seen some discrepancy online as to whether the _compute_shared function should use .Q or .Qp for the third argument; though most show Qp.  I tried with .Q and get a non-zero shared secret, but its value does not change with changes to Qp (the other party's public key) - so this does not seem correct.  As an aside, I also noticed that the function returns almost immediately when using .Qp, but takes a long time to return with .Q; in both cases the return value is 0 (success).

Comment: Correction: when using .Qp in the mbedtls_ecdh_compute_shared() function, the return value is 0xFFFFB380.  I am not able to find what this means.

Comment: I've found that 0xFFFFB380 = -0x4C80 which is MBEDTLS_ERR_ECP_INVALID_KEY.  I populated Qp using the public key of a second ECDH context created in the same way as the first - so I don't know why it is invalid.  If I use the public key of the second ECDH context directly as the argument to _compute_shared(), then it works. So, there seems to be an issue with putting the key values into Qp.

Comment: What's in `HostStaticPublicKey_X` & `HostStaticPublicKey_Y`?

Comment: They contain the X and Y coordinates of the other party's public key.  To aid in debugging, I now have them being loaded from another local ECDH context like this: mbedtls_mpi_read_binary(&ECDH_Context_Static.Q.X, HostStaticPublicKkey_X, key_size);

Comment: The above was supposed to be "...write_binary..."

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the mbedtls_ecdh_compute_shared() function to work by placing the other party's public key into the PRIVATE key of a temporary ECDH context (created as shown in the first three lines of code in the original question post), then using that private key as the mbedtls_ecp_point argument:

with the other party's public key in arrays HostPublicX and HostPublicY,

```
mbedtls_mpi_read_binary(&TempECDHContext.Q.X, HostPublicX, key_size);
mbedtls_mpi_read_binary(&TempECDHContext.Q.Y, HostPublicY, key_size);

mbedtls_ecdh_compute_shared(&ECDH_Context_Static.grp, &ECDH_Context_Static.z, &TempECDHContext.Q, &ECDH_Context_Static.d, NULL, NULL);
```

While this works, I am still curious about the .Qp point in the ECDH context and why the mbedtls_ecdh_compute_shared() function fails if .Qp is used as the ecp_point argument.